Row missing issue with Oracle Analytic Publisher (datamodel) when sourced from OBIEE (Subject Area)
Just found out that when i imported an OBIEE analysis with 20000+ rows to a BI Publisher data model.
After create report and export out result. There are data missing.
Remark:
For analysis, export result are 20000+ rows.
For report, export result are always exactly 10000 rows
I did try to pass SQL in datamodel (same as OBIEE logic), I can get all data (20000+ out)
So i am pretty sure reason is from analysis to datamodel. But no idea what part is limiting it.
Is it caused by some parameter limiting it?
